# Android FragmentPagerAdapter can't change tag of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am developing a simple web beowser with dynamic tabs to allow user to add/remove them. I use `FragmentPagerAdapter`, `ViewPager` and `TabLayout` to do this. If I create 2 tabs (add 2 fragments to list) and then remove the second one, everything work well and I can add another fragment to list. But if I add 2 and then remove the firs one and try to add new fragment to list, I recieve exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment Page{162e3786 #1 id=0x7f0d007d android:switcher:2131558525:1}: was android:switcher:2131558525:1 now android:switcher:2131558525:0
```

I think thats because each fragment has unique id inside `FragmentPagerAdapter`. 2 fragments will have id's 0 and 1. If I remove the first item(id is 0) and then add new one(id will be 1). But item with id 1 is already exists! Is there a way to change id's programmatically or set id's when creating fragments? Thanks in advance!

My `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Page> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Page> pages) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = pages;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        int index = pages.indexOf(object);
        if (index == -1){
            return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
        } else {
            return index;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
        trans.remove((Fragment) object);
        trans.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally, after a hours of search and tries I found the solution.
To fix that you need to override `getItemId()` method of `FragmentPagerAdapter` in which you have to return a unique id for each fragment.